# Maximization of a function within a unit square

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I work in a unit square. I have some conditions under which areas within the unit square are defined. Say for simplicity that there are two conditions which define two areas. For example, if y > 1/2 or if y > ax + b , we are in area 1 and otherwise, in area 2. I have represented two possible situations in the figures ([Case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciGqD.jpg)
[Case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3bAi.jpg))

I want to find a and b (which are strictly positive) such that a*(area 1) + b*(area 2) is maximized. I think this is an easy problem to solve by hand, except if you have 7 different conditions. I am wondering if there is a way to automate that in Mathematica. The problem I have is that as conditions change, the shapes of the areas also change, which makes it difficult to compute them automatically (see the figures).

I would already be very happy if I could find all possible shapes given my seven conditions.

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Welcome to MMA.SE! Please show us also what you already tried (i.e. code), Otherwise you may not attract many answers and/or the question may be closed.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do, but here's a thought: this calculates the area that satisfies a a given condition,
    `Integrate[Boole[condition[x,y]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`

From that, you can go on and use any optimization algorithm in the market (`Maximize`, for example). If you want to do it numerically, which might be easier, you can use `NIntegrate`, rather than `Integrate`.

Comment: @YvesKlett Klett I don't have any code as I do not have any idea on how to do it. In the beginning, because I had few conditions, I simply computed the areas by hand and used mathematica to maximize. But this is very very boring to do for 7 conditions.

Comment: @yohbs That is what I thought at first but then, the Integrate will have to be written differently for each case, doesn't it ? For example, in the figures I provided, the integrals for the computation of area 1 are not the same. Hence, I would have to write two different "Integrate" based on whether I am in the first or second figure. It is possible to dos so here but with my seven conditions, I would have to write dozens of possibilities. I'm afraid I'm not very clear.

Comment: It will be much simpler if you give concrete, explicit  examples, with formulas and numbers, both for the areas and for the function you wish to optimize

Comment: @yohbs Ok. So, x and y belong to the 0,1 interval since we are in the unit square. Say we want to find the area 1 defined by y > 1/2 or y> ax. We want to find a such that we maximize a*(area 1). In this case, if a <=1, the function to maximize will be a- (a^2)/2. Hence, the value of a we want is 1. I know how to get that value once I have found the function to maximize but I do not know how to find that function automatically in mathematica. I do not think I can use Integrate because the shape of the area 1 changes. For example, the function is different if a >1.

Comment: Please edit all relevant info into the question.

Answer (score 4):

In your comment you gave an explicit example of finding the value of $a$ which maximized $a$ times the area of the region of $x,y\in [0,1]$ such that $y\geq ax$ or $y\geq1/2$. You claim the optimum value of $a$ is 1, but this appears to be incorrect:

```
Integrate[a Boole[y >= a x || y >= 1/2], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
Plot[%, {a, 0, 3}]
```

$$\begin{cases}
 a & a\leq 0 \\
 \frac{a+4}{8} & a=1 \\
 \frac{1}{8} (4 a+1) & \frac{1}{2}<a<1\lor a>1 \\
 \frac{1}{2} \left(2 a-a^2\right) & \text{True}
\end{cases}$$

[image]

`RegionPlot` confirms this. Are you sure you're calculating things correctly?

Also, it appears that your original question of maximizing $a A_1+b A_2$ has a trivial solution:

```
expr1 = Integrate[a Boole[y >= 1/2 || y >= a x + b], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
expr2 = Integrate[b Boole[y < 1/2 && y < b + a x], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
Simplify[expr1 + expr2 /. a -> b]
(*Out: b*)
```

As a result, the maximization problem is not well-defined, since the product $a A_1+b A_2$ diverges as $a\rightarrow\infty,b\rightarrow\infty$, so I'm not sure your question makes sense.